# Вылет при запуске приложения java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Есть приложение, использующее native библиотеку. При запуске на android 5.0 (Asus ) всё работает отлично, но если запускать на андроиде версии ниже (4.0.3-Sony Xperia P и 4.4 МТС ), приложение падает, в лог пишет следующее:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                           at com.snostorm.rakdroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2027)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:  1486 cannot locate 'atof'...

                                                                           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
                                                                           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
                                                                           at com.snostorm.rakdroid.BotService.<clinit>(BotService.java:37)
                                                                           at com.snostorm.rakdroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2027) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Пробовал подключить библиотеки stdc++ и stlport_shared, не помогло.

**UPD**
При этом, если я убираю код, который использует atof, я получаю

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000020 (code=1), thread 12787 (ostorm.rakdroid)
```

Comment: Проблема, судя по всему, кроется в строке `cannot locate 'atof'`.

Comment: Именно поэтому я пытался подключить stdc++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, проблему решить проблему можно 2-мя способами: либо убрать код, использующий atof, либо использовать `APP_PLATFORM := android-19`.

SIGSEGV вызывал этот код:

```
int ret=0;
if((ret = pthread_kill(t, 0)) != 0){//<--тут
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, call_from_thread, NULL);
}
```

Но на андроид 5.0+ всё работает. Чудеса...